# How to add createDatabaseIfNotExist in sql server application.properties of spring boot application

Tags: sql-server, spring-boot, microservices, liquibase

I am new to spring boot and microservices. 
I am using sql server as database for my demo microservice app. I want to create a database on the start of application execution if it is not present in addition to that there are multiple parameters which i want to add, following is the application.properties file which I have created but the line of spring.datasourse.url is failing.

```js
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=Hello?useUnicode=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC&createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false 
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=Temp1234
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql = true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = none
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE 
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl 
spring.liquibase.change-log=classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml
```

But if it throws fallowing error in execution:

```js
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The databaseName property exceeds the maximum number of 128 characters.
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1778) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:307) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1105) ~[spring-context-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) [spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) [spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) [spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) [spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
 at com.sha.microserviceusermanagement.MicroserviceUserManagementApplication.main(MicroserviceUserManagementApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The databaseName property exceeds the maximum number of 128 characters.
 at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:307) ~[liquibase-core-3.6.3.jar:na]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1837) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1774) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
 ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The databaseName property exceeds the maximum number of 128 characters.
 at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:228) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.4.0.jre8.jar:na]
 at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.ValidateMaxSQLLoginName(SQLServerConnection.java:1066) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.4.0.jre8.jar:na]
 at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:1211) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.4.0.jre8.jar:na]
 at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:1077) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.4.0.jre8.jar:na]
 at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:623) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.4.0.jre8.jar:na]
 at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:136) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
 at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:369) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
 at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:198) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
 at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:467) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
 at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:541) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
 at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
 at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
 at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$eeb1ae86.invoke(<generated>) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
 at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:749) ~[spring-aop-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:136) ~[spring-aop-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:124) ~[spring-aop-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688) ~[spring-aop-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
 at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$24a86ede.getConnection(<generated>) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
 at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:302) ~[liquibase-core-3.6.3.jar:na]
 ... 20 common frames omitted
```

Following is the db.changelog-master.xml

```js
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
                        http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.4.xsd">
  <include file="db/changelog/db.changelog-1.0.xml"/>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

Following is the db.changelog-1.0.xml

```js
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog" xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.5.xsd">
    <changeSet author="sha" id="200320191">
        <sql>
            CREATE TABLE user (
                id BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                username VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
                password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
                name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
                role VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
                CONSTRAINT PK_id PRIMARY KEY (id)
            );
        </sql>
        <rollback>
            DROP TABLE library;
        </rollback>
    </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

Comment: any one, please help, no info on google ....

Comment: The error in your logs point to SpringLiquibase. Can you please provide your db.changelog-master.xml file? Maybe the db name config error is there.

Comment: First error in error stack points to data base connection string length. 
Anyways, I have added the XML files in the question.

Comment: anyone has any details ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the connection string.

Try without using `databaseName`

According to your xml, your db name is `user'. So try:

`spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433/user?useUnicode=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC&createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false`

Comment: where is applicationName ?

Comment: Sorry, meant databaseName